# What is this piece of training equipment called?

Tags: american-football, equipment, terminology, training

What is this fake player cutout thing called? It appears to be mesh. It looks like it's used simply as a visual point-of-reference for certain drills.

You can see it being used in [this video](https://twitter.com/footwork_king1/status/629765139475009536).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a mannequin for skill training.

Is it used in *football/soccer* training to increase precision penalty (so is called **(slave) defensive template barrier**)

In *american football* and *basketball* is often easy to find it called as **man defensive mannequin**.

I do not know if it exists a "real" name for it, but those are probably the easy denomination you can find for it

i.e. commercial links [basketball](http://www.spartansbasketballacademytt.com/equipment.html) and [soccer](http://www.goals4sports.com/span%20style=color%20rgb%2858%2058%2058%29%20font-family%20comic%20sans%20ms%20font-size%2013px%20line-height%2016px%20white-space%20normal%20soccer_wall_pro_single_mannequin/span)

Comment: Good answer, but it would be better with a couple of links to references that use the term that way!

Comment: Of course; but having a complete answer is preferable.  Thanks for updating with links!

Comment: I have edited the reply with commercial links, if is it not possible to insert that links you can easly search that words on google images

Comment: I am not sure of its soccer user but I have never seen these used in football in my 30 years in the game.  Basketball it is used to teach players to not care about defenders on their jump shots.  You can leave it by the three point line and take shots right over it... useful, debatable.

Comment: Something very similar is used to training in free kick: http://www.liski.it/EN-en/catalogo.asp?Catalogo=SPORT%20EQUIPMENT%3Cbr%3EAND%20TRAINING%20MATERIALS&CatalogoId=24&Categoria=Training%20equipments&CategoriaId=4416&sottocategoria=KICK%20WALLS&sottocategoriaid=4459 and also http://www.gettyimages.it/detail/fotografie-di-cronaca/italian-coach-marcello-lippi-pushes-a-free-kick-fotografie-di-cronaca/71396779